# Test end-user's JS/CSS performance and change variable accordingly

Tags: javascript, css, performance, 3d

I'm creating a portfolio site that uses real-time calculation of mouse position / mobile accelerator(gyroscope) to move 3D panels around in reaction to those readings. It runs great on powerful computers/iPhone, but not so much on weaker laptops etc.

I have some different variables set for different device-types, but I'd like to detect how fast the user's computer is processing the JS/CSS and change the rate of position update based on that result.

I've seen answers related to testing performance with `Date.now()` and `performance.now()`, but haven't found anything about reacting to a user's test-result.

The piece of code in question that I'm currently using:

```
function ifWin(){
    return ( ( navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) ); }
    if(ifWin()) {initialize_pc(); runPc = setInterval( run_pc, 30 );
    } else {
        /*do nothing*/
    }
```

I want to be able to detect how fast a user's processing and change the setInterval rate based on that. Fast rate (30ms) and for slower computers a slower rate (150ms). I'm a JS novice, could anyone explain the best method of doing that?

**UPDATE:** I tried using requestAnimationFrame with no change in performance on weak machines. Changing setInterval Rate definitely helped, but requestAnimationFrame doesn't seem to lower the rate based on performance.

If it helps, here's he whole function that I'm running with requestAnimationFrame:

```
function run_pc() {

    requestAnimationFrame(run_pc);

    perspective.cx += ( perspective.tx - perspective.cx ) * .5;
    perspective.cy += ( perspective.ty - perspective.cy ) * .5;

    page1.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + perspective.cy * -.5 + 'vw, ' + perspective.cx * .5 + 'vw, ' + perspective.cx  * -2 + 'vw) rotateX(' + perspective.cx * 1.3 + 'deg) rotateY(' + perspective.cy * -1 + 'deg) rotateZ(0deg)';

    detailPanel.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(' + perspective.cy * -.5 + 'vw, ' + perspective.cx * -1 + 'vmin, ' + perspective.cx * -10 + 'vw) rotateX(' + perspective.cx * 1.2 + 'deg) rotateY(' + perspective.cy * -1 + 'deg) rotateZ(0deg)';

}

function ifWin(){
    return ( ( navigator.platform.indexOf("Win") != -1) ); }
    if(ifWin()) {initialize_pc(); run_pc();
    } else {
        /*do nothing*/
}
```

**UPDATE:** I got a performance increase by removing the " * .5 " from `perspective.cx += ( perspective.tx - perspective.cx ) * .5;`

I guess that was too much calculation for some machines. The purpose of that being to add a ease-out effect to the motions. The easing was nice, tho. I'll try to find a less math-intensive way to do that.

Comment: Perhaps what you need is the [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/) function, which automatically calls itself no faster than the screen can refresh.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed like a good solution and after reading your link I'll definitely be using that from now on - sadly still has the same performance lag ( the 3D position jump/flicker/stutters on weak laptops).

Comment: @Blazemonger I'm new to StackOverflow, otherwise I'd upvote your comment. Thanks again.